# If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d>0$, prove that $\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{abc}{(b+c+d)(c+d+a)(d+a+b)}}\le\frac43$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> If $a$, $b$, $c$, $d>0$, prove that
> \[\sum_{\rm cyc}\left(\frac{abc}{(b+c+d)(c+d+a)(d+a+b)}\right)^\frac13\le\frac43.\]

I tried Carlson on the denominator but the following are all wrong.
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}}{\sqrt[3]{bcd}+\sqrt[3]{cda}+\sqrt[3]{dab}}\le\frac43;\\
\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}}{\sqrt[3]{a^2d}+\sqrt[3]{b^2d}+\sqrt[3]{c^2d}}\le\frac43;\\
\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}}{\sqrt[3]{abc}+\sqrt[3]{ddd}+\sqrt[3]{abc}}=\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{abc}}{2\sqrt[3]{abc}+d}\le\frac43.\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Check: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1745857p11380402

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply AM-GM to each term as so:
$$
\sum_\mbox{cyc}\left(\frac{abc}{(b+c+d)(c+d+a)(d+a+b)} \right)^{1/3}\le \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{b}{b+c+d}+\frac{c}{c+d+a}+\frac{a}{d+a+b}\right)+\\ +
 \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{d}{c+d+a}+\frac{b}{d+a+b}+\frac{c}{a+b+c}\right)+\\ +
\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{d}{d+a+b}+\frac{a}{a+b+c}+\frac{c}{b+c+d}\right)+\\ +
\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{b}{a+b+c}+\frac{d}{b+c+d}+\frac{a}{c+d+a}\right)=4/3.
$$

Comment: It is very nice.

Comment: @RiverLi thanks! It seems too obvious for am-gm, so I triple checked... Now you checking it gives me sigh of relief

Comment: Yes, I checked it.